# Alert Dialog widget is causing A RenderFlex overflowed by 92 pixels on the bottom

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Would appreciate it if anyone can help me out with the problem I am having while developing the flutter app, Since I am relatively new to flutter, I am using the Expanded(parent) widget under which I am using multiple widgets, & Click on of the widget I am showing alert dialog which has text input, but when someone focuses on the text input I am getting this error. I am wrapping my alert dialog widget under the SingleChildScrollView widget but still getting the error.

```
///--------Parent WIdget Code------------------------Expanded(
  // flex: 1,
  // child: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      // height: 100,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return snapshot.hasData
                      ? Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 70, 0, 10),
                              child: const Text("Select Shuttle ID",
                                  style:
                                      TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ),
                            Container(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 10),
                                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                    hint: const Text("Select Shuttle ID"),
                                    value: dropdownValue,
                                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                                    elevation: 16,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.deepPurple),
                                    underline: Container(
                                      height: 2,
                                      width: 50,
                                      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                                    ),
                                    onChanged: (String? value) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        dropdownValue = value!;
                                        print(
                                            'Selected One:  $dropdownValue');
                                        filterData(dropdownValue);
                                        // print(list);
                                      });
                                    },
                                    items: getListData()))
                          ],
                        )
                      : const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            strokeWidth: 3,
                          ),
                        );
                },
              )),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      // height: 10,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 50, 10, 0),
                      child: Wrap(children: [
                        InkWell(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                                child: Image.asset(
                                    'assets/images/home-page.png'),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              const Text(
                                'Home',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            GetHome(context);
                          },
                        ),
                      ])),
                  Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 70, 10, 10),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            child: BatteryIndicator(
                              batteryFromPhone: false,
                              batteryLevel: batteryLevel,
                              style: BatteryIndicatorStyle.values[0],
                              colorful: true,
                              showPercentNum: true,
                              mainColor: Colors.blue,
                              size: 25.0,
                              ratio: 4.0,
                              showPercentSlide: true,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 25,
                          ),
                          const Text(
                            'Battery',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          )
                        ],
                      ))
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 10,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      // height: 10,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 50, 10, 0),
                      child: Wrap(children: [
                        InkWell(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                                child: Image.asset(
                                    'assets/images/inventory.png'),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              const Text(
                                'Inventory Check',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            GetInventory(context);
                          },
                        ),
                      ])),
                  Container(
                      // height: 10,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 50, 10, 0),
                      child: Wrap(children: [
                        InkWell(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                                child:
                                    Image.asset('assets/images/distance.png'),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              const Text(
                                'Pallet Distance',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            EnterPalletDistance(context);
                          },
                        ),
                      ]))
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 20,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    // height: 100,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(90, 50, 10, 0),
                    child: Wrap(children: [
                      Material(
                        elevation: 20,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          child: Text('STOP'),
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: Colors.red,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 50, vertical: 20),
                              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Stop(context);
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )),
  // )
);
```

[image]

```
///-------------------- Alert Dialog Code--------------------
    EnterPalletDistance(context) {
      final isSelected = CheckIfShuttleSelected(context);
      // print(isSelected);
      if (isSelected) {
        // print("CONTEXT IS: $context");
        TextEditingController palletDistanceController = TextEditingController();
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                // alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                // scrollable: true,
                title: const Text('Enter Pallet Distance'),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child:
                      //  Column(
                      //   children: <Widget>[
                      // child:
                      Container(
                    // height: 100,
                    // padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        // print(value);
                      },
                      controller: palletDistanceController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Enter Distance',
                      ),
                    ),
                    //   ),
                    // ],
                  ),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text('Submit'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.green),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            })
```

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot.

Comment: GIF image is attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible Solution.
Give Scaffold this property

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

Comment: still, giving the same exception? I don't know much about android development, currently, I am running the code in the emulator & exception is being shown in my console, how would it behave while running the APK in the device itself?

Comment: In production (release mode), the yellow lines won't be visible and the user won't even know about the overflow, but this isn't a good practice and you must avoid it.